# How to use stings as ticks on plots?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

If both the x and y axis are numbers, I can display text on the plot by using the functions `num2str`, `cellstr`, and `strtrim`. These functions format the coordinate values into a cell array of strings, which can then be displayed with the function `text`:

```
strValues = strtrim(cellstr(num2str(
  [X(:) Y(:)],
  '(%d,%d)'
)));
text(
  X,
  Y,
  strValues,
 'VerticalAlignment',
 'bottom'
);
```

But what if the x axis contains strings instead of numbers?

```
X=['john' 'jack' 'mary'.....] 
Y=[0 1 2 3]
```

How do I then show the y values on all of the data plots?

Answer (score 1):

You can create the plot with categoricals...

```
X = categorical( {'john','jack','mary','jack'} );
Y = [1 2 3 3];

figure;
plot( X, Y, '.', 'markersize', 20 );
```

[image: plot]

You can then place `text` the same as with numeric data

```
 text( categorical({'jack'}), 2, 'test' )
```

To add the value as a label to all the points, you can use `X` directly:

```
text( X, Y + 0.2, cellstr( num2str( Y(:) ) ) )
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**1st way:**
Juse normal plotting (you may need to enumerate your categories first though) and than set the ticks of your axis. This allows maximum flexiblity at the cost of a potential mix-up

```
set(gca, 'xTick',1:length(X), 'xTickLabel',X)
```

The first ensures that all ticks are plottet while the second name-value-pair renames those ticks. When it comes to names or longer strings, you may also want to rotate the ticks labels with ['xtickangle'](https://it.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xtickangle.html).

The MathWorks uses this workaround even in its [examples](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/change-tick-marks-and-tick-labels-of-graph-1.html):

```
x = linspace(-10,10,200);
y = cos(x);
plot(x,y)
xticks([-3*pi -2*pi -pi 0 pi 2*pi 3*pi])
xticklabels({'-3\pi','-2\pi','-\pi','0','\pi','2\pi','3\pi'})
```

**2nd way:** If you have [`categorial`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/categorical.html) data, you can plot it right away. Have a look at the [doc here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/plot-categorical-data.html).

Comment: The question is slightly ambiguous, but I believe it is about adding `text` to a plot with non-numeric X data, rather than just being able to plot non-numeric X labels. The actual "I can do this" example by the OP is talking about using `text`. This is why I rejected your question edit, as it frames the question to more closely reflect your answer, which isn't necessarily the original intent

Comment: @Wolfie no problem; that is what I commented in the edit summary. I just wasn't sure what exactly the question is so my edit had to be biased